# No sound after upgrading 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound, lts, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and did

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

The upgrade took about 30 minutes to complete.
After restarting the computer the sound does not play in (Youtube, Rhytmbox...). What should I do?.

Answer (score 0):

That was not a good idea to upgrade from this ppa.
You can try to fix it by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

but there is no guarantee that all installed stuff is removed correctly.

Comment: Still not working. Any additional advices? I am becoming desperate a bit. Maybe reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: Reinstalling ubuntu and never upgrading from `xorg-edgers` is a good idea.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu and it worked again. But, I tried upgrading it using

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

And again, sound was lost. Is there any other way to keep the upgrades but to fix the sound?

Comment: Did you use xorg-edgers again?

Comment: No, I didn't use it this time